# Flutter - How to add first top and last bottom list with divider() on ListView.separated()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I added a divider on my list but i also want to have a divider line on the top part and last end part on the list. Because the divider line are only in the middle of each list.

```
ListView.separated(
 itemCount: user.personList.length,
 separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
 itemBuilder: (context, index){
   return ListTile(
    title: Text(user.personList[index].id)
  )
 }
)
```

Comment: `Because the divider line are only in the middle of each list ` that’s why it called DIVIDER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add divider on top and bottom in following way.

you have to increase length by 2 and on 0 and length-1 return container, which will give make [divider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html) more clearly. if you want dedicated divider then you can also use divider widget.

```
ListView.separated(
      itemCount: user.personList.length + 2,
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index == 0 || index == user.personList.length + 1) {
          return Divider(
            color: Colors.black,
            thickness: 2,
          );
        }
        return ListTile(title: Text((index - 1).toString())); // note: you have to access element by -1;
      },
    ),
```

Comment: Why not just put a `Divider` right above and below the `ListView` in the widget tree (instead of as elements of the ListView itself)? Makes the code more simple.

Comment: yes definitely it is possible @JJuice but it will increase more boilerplate code which decreases readability of code. to do so we have to wrap list view in column and then we have to add divider above and below listview.

Comment: Ok. As a third suggestion, you could also wrap the `ListView` with a `Padding` widget, where you set only the `top` and `bottom` padding.